# What are the security risks associated with an automated login script?

Tags: security

I have a remote server that only allows logins through a browser https request. I want to download images from it, and cache them and use them in a local job. What are the security risks with automating this job using the python requests library assuming the local server is secure and stores the password securely?

Comment: If it's through an http request (instead of an https request) who cares?  It's going across the internet in plain text anyway.

Comment: its https. I'm talking about blatant security holes from doing this.

Comment: Security risk would be how you handle the storing of credentials in your script in addition to how the data is transmitted.

Comment: Its stored in the jenkins credentials plugin, so I would assume that as long as jenkins is secure its a safe bet?

Comment: Your question as written is too vague.

Comment: As @Zoredache said....expound on it, but it needs to exist on security.stackexchange.com instead in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of vague as written, but...

> I have a remote server that only allows logins through a browser https
>   request.

Er.  Basic or digest authentication, I assume?  Or Windows integrated security, if you're using IIS?

Assuming that you're just pulling down images from some kind of password-protected web server location via standard HTTPS, the biggest risk I can see is the credentials.  You would mainly be risking unauthorized people viewing the images, or maybe someone replacing the images with something malicious if the server is compromised.

(Unless you mean "images" as in "executables" that you download and execute.  Then more the second thing.)

But it's possible that I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: Images means pngs from a tableau server. My assumption is that since requests cookies are not stored on disk, that really the only risk is stored credentials.

Comment: Stored credentials and people viewing the pngs without permission.  It sounds like the stored credentials would be low-privilege, yes?  If you're not concerned about people viewing the pngs without permission, and the credentials are read-only for just the pngs, you might decide that the risk level is acceptable.